# For loop is adding a space on generated CSS vars

Tags: css, less

This Less;

```
@sizes: xsmall, small, medium, medium-large, large, xlarge, xxlarge;

.init-spacing(@i) when (@i > 0) {
  
  @size: extract(@sizes, @i);
  
  // MARGINS --------------------------------------------
  .margin-@{size} { margin: var(--spacing-@size); }
  
  // PADDING --------------------------------------------
  .padding-@{size} { padding: var(--spacing-@size); }
  
  .init-spacing(@i - 1);
}

.init-spacing(length(@sizes));
```

Produces this output;

```
.margin-xxlarge {
  margin: var(--spacing- xxlarge); <-- Notice the added space.
}
.padding-xxlarge {
  padding: var(--spacing- xxlarge); <-- Notice the added space.
}
....
```

I'm curious why the css class names don't have an added space but their usage in the css vars being generated DOES have an added space. Most importantly, how do I get rid of that added space so the css vars are generated correctly valid?

Here's a [Codepen to tinker with](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/GRyvKbe) displaying the issue on the compiled css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space is added by the concatenation of `@size` to `--spacing-@size` as less always adds a single space between the variables, eg the result of `@size@size` is `xsmall xsmall`.

To remove the unwanted space, use `~"--spacing-@{size}"`:

```less
// MARGINS --------------------------------------------
.margin-@{size} { margin: var(~"--spacing-@{size}"); }
  
// PADDING --------------------------------------------
.padding-@{size} { padding: var(~"--spacing-@{size}"); }
```

Related Issue: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1375

Comment: Thank you much, when you've used primarily Sass/scss for so long the Less stuff can throw some curve balls. Oh and add the trailing `"` to close the string missing from the example. Cheers!

Comment: @ChrisW. No worries, good pick up on the example code, updated now..